# how to make a proc available compile time and run time

Tags: compile-time, nim-lang, multilinestring

I have a nim proc that dedents a multiline string based on the whitespace
of the first indented line:

```
import strutils

proc dedent(s: string): string
    {.noSideEffect.} =
    var prefix = ""
    for line in s.splitLines(keepEol=true):
        if prefix == "" and line.len > 0:
            for j in 0..<line.len:
                if line[j] != ' ':
                    prefix = line[0..j-1]
                    break
        if line.startsWith(prefix):
            result.add(line[prefix.len .. high(line)])
        else:
            result.add(line)

when isMainModule:
    echo dedent """
        cat:
          - meow
          - purr

        dog:
          - bark
          - drool
        """
```

it nicely outputs:

```
cat:
  - meow
  - purr

dog:
  - bark
  - drool
```

but inspecting the intermediate C code, I see:

```
STRING_LITERAL(TM_9amIjLnWbK7OR9aPA8dicbaQ_14, "        cat:\012          - meow\012          - purr\012        \012       "
" dog:\012          - bark\012          - drool\012        ", 112);
```

so the dedenting is done at run-time. I can add the `compileTime` pragma to the proc:

```
proc dedent(s: string): string
    {.noSideEffect,compileTime.} =
```

and then the C output changes to:

```
STRING_LITERAL(TM_9amIjLnWbK7OR9aPA8dicbaQ_3, "cat:\012  - meow\012  - purr\012\012dog:\012  - bark\012  - drool\012", 48);
```

Which is exactly what I want, multi-line strings that are indented to their surrounding on every line, but don't have that extra indentation in the executable.

But adding that pragma, I can no longer access `dedent` at run-time, e.g. when adding:

```
    import os
    if paramCount() > 0:
        for i in 1..paramCount():
            echo dedent paramStr(i)
```

to `isMainModule`, you get the error:

> Error: request to generate code for .compileTime proc: dedent

I looked at the source for `splitLines` in `strutils.nim` to see if there was some other pragma that I could apply, but I did not find anything that would work.

I now about the `static` statement, but would prefer that the compiler optimises this at compile time without me having to sprinkle this in.

How can I get this to work both compile-time as well as run-time without reverting to the use of `static`? 
Do I need to compile the proc from a seperate `.nim` module? Or is there a compiler option, pragma, something else, that I am missing?

Comment: As a side note, `func` is an alias for a `proc` with `.noSideEffect.`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the `--implicitStatic:on` flag to the Nim compiler to enable implicit compile time evaluation of procedures.

These procedures **cannot** have the `compileTime` pragma.

Answer (score 3):

To force the evaluate of any expression at compile-time, you can use `static` in the following way:

```
when isMainModule:
    echo static(dedent"""
        cat:
          - meow
          - purr

        dog:
          - bark
          - drool
        """)
```

All expressions assigned to constants are also evaluated at compile-time, so this is another way to achieve the same.